# Why Android's TextView custom bold font is outlined by default?

Tags: android, text

I’m using custom font for entire application as follows (I found this approach on Stack Overflow):

```
public class Application extends android.app.Application {
    private static final String DEFAULT_NORMAL_BOLD_FONT_FILENAME = "HelveticaNeueCyrMedium.otf";
    private static final String DEFAULT_NORMAL_BOLD_ITALIC_FONT_FILENAME = "HelveticaNeueCyrBoldItalic.otf";
    private static final String DEFAULT_NORMAL_ITALIC_FONT_FILENAME = "HelveticaNeueCyrItalic.otf";
    private static final String DEFAULT_NORMAL_NORMAL_FONT_FILENAME = "HelveticaNeueCyrRoman.otf";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        try {
            setDefaultFonts();
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
         …
        }
    }

    private void setDefaultFonts() throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
        final Typeface bold = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), DEFAULT_NORMAL_BOLD_FONT_FILENAME);
        final Typeface italic = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), DEFAULT_NORMAL_ITALIC_FONT_FILENAME);
        final Typeface boldItalic = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), DEFAULT_NORMAL_BOLD_ITALIC_FONT_FILENAME);
        final Typeface normal = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), DEFAULT_NORMAL_NORMAL_FONT_FILENAME);

        Field defaultField = Typeface.class.getDeclaredField("DEFAULT");
        defaultField.setAccessible(true);
        defaultField.set(null, normal);

        Field defaultBoldField = Typeface.class.getDeclaredField("DEFAULT_BOLD");
        defaultBoldField.setAccessible(true);
        defaultBoldField.set(null, bold);

        Field sDefaults = Typeface.class.getDeclaredField("sDefaults");
        sDefaults.setAccessible(true);
        sDefaults.set(null, new Typeface[]{normal, bold, italic, boldItalic});
    }
}
```

On emulators with API level 14, 15 and on some real devices (like Lenovo A789 or HTC Desire S) `TextView` draws bold font outlined (thin stroke around letters, see [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xF0S.png)).

For API level 21+ and other devices it draws bold text as expected without the outline. (Bold text is set by TextView's attr in xml layout: `android:textStyle="bold"`)

Could someone tell me how to disable outlined text and draw it normally (like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umsbb.png))?

Comment: What custom font are you trying to implement?

Comment: I'm trying to use Helvetica